# ffmpeg can't create Ogg Vorbis

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, ogg

I'm trying to convert a set of .PNG files and a .WAV file into an Ogg Vorbis video using ffmpeg on Windows 7. When I run "ffmpeg -codecs" I can see libvorbis listed, but when I try to use it in a command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -r 1 -i "dir\%04d.png" -i "dir\audio.wav" -vcodec libvorbis -r 25 out.ogv
```

I get the error:

> Invalid encoder type 'libvorbis'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Vorbis is not video. It's an [audio codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis), typically embedded in the Ogg container format. Maybe that's where the confusion comes from.

You want to use [Theora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theora) with `libtheora`. Also, you should specify both video and audio codecs, rather than having ffmpeg choose one. I typically add `-shortest` to tell ffmpeg to stop encoding whenever there are no more images or the audio track is finished.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1 -i "dir\%04d.png" -i "dir\audio.wav" -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis -shortest -r 25 out.ogv
```

Check the [Theora/Vorbis encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide) for quality options.

Comment: Wow, the .mp4 file is 10.2MB. The same data in .ogv is 87.6MB.

Comment: Ah, removing the "-r 25" brings it down to 16.4MB.

Comment: The file size depends on the quality too. You have to experiment with that.